# How to extract all parts of time

Tags: r

How can I extract all the parts of time Hours, minutes seconds and milliseconds from this vector

```
d = as.POSIXct(c( "2015-09-08 17:42:07.456 GMT","2015-09-08 17:42:19.778 GMT"))

library(lubridate)
    hours =  hour(d)
    minutes =  minute(d)
    sec =  d...?
    milliseconds =  d...?
```

I was trying to use lubridate package above but how do you get the second and millisecond separated?

```
strsplit(as.character(second(d)), ".")
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for packages:

```
d <- as.POSIXct(c( "2015-09-08 17:42:07.456 GMT","2015-09-08 17:42:19.778 GMT"))

d1 <- as.POSIXlt(d)

d1$sec
## [1]  7.456 19.778

d1$min
## [1] 42 42

d1$hour
## [1] 17 17
```

You can grok the ms from the decimal portion of `sec`.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = as.POSIXct(c( "2015-09-08 17:42:07.456 GMT","2015-09-08 17:42:19.778 GMT"))

library(lubridate)
hours<-  hour(d)
minutes  <-   minute(d)
sec  <-   floor(second(d))
milliseconds  <-   1000*(second(d)-sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `strsplit`, you coud do `strsplit(as.character(round(as.POSIXlt(d)$sec, 3)), ".", T)`